# Backend export Crystal Reports to PDF

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports-2016

I'm newbie to Crystal Reports and would like to know, which way to go.

My challenge:
A web-service consumer asks for a PDF on a specific report (name of RPT-file).
The called web-service shall generate report output as PDF and send it to the consumer.
The machine, where the service shall run, has an installed service "SAP Crystal Reports Server 2016".

Actually I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 13 SP27".
I'm thinking of an implementation in C#.

I tried lots of examples but none seems to be basis for my challenge.

Am I on the correct track?

Any hint is welcome...